# How to convert vtk legacy files to vtu format

Tags: vtk, paraview

I want to convert legacy `.vtk` files into binary files, preferably `.vtu` files, because I am using an Unstructured Grid.
To do so I adapted the ConvertFile-Example from http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/ConvertFile

```
#include <string>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkGenericDataObjectReader.h>
#include <vtkVersion.h>
#include <vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter.h>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc < 3)
    {
    std::cerr << "Required arguments: input.vtk output.vtu" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

  std::string inputFileName = argv[1];
  std::string outputFileName = argv[2];

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
  reader->SetFileName(inputFileName.c_str());
  reader->Update();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter>::New();
  writer->SetFileName(outputFileName.c_str());
  writer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
  writer->Update();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But when I use this to convert my legacy file, I lose all Cell Data after the first set. In this minimal example of my legacy file Scal_1 is in the `.vtu` file but Scal_2 is not.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.1
Lattice Boltzmann data
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 9 INT 
0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 
0 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 0 
0 2 0 1 2 0 2 2 0 

CELLS 4 20
4 0 1 3 4 
4 1 2 4 5 
4 3 4 6 7 
4 4 5 7 8 

CELL_TYPES 4
8 8 8 8 

CELL_DATA 4
SCALARS Scal_1 DOUBLE
LOOKUP_TABLE default
1 2 1 0 

SCALARS Scal_2 DOUBLE
LOOKUP_TABLE default
1 3 2 1
```

I am still new to `vtk`. Should I use another reader or writer? Or is something completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the reader you chose is getting confused by having the input file containing 2 cell data arrays both marked as scalars. So with this the reader only outputs one cell data array. My suggestion is to use ParaView, specifically the *pvpython* executable, to convert the files. The corresponding Python code would look something like:

```
from paraview.simple import *
r = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=['input.vtk'] )
w = XMLUnstructuredGridWriter()
w.FileName = 'output.vtu'
w.UpdatePipeline()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine). Install with

```
pip3 install meshio
```

and run

```
meshio convert in.vtk out.vtu
```